# Website can't be accessed in internet

Tags: webserver

From the recent crazy effort of myself and help from the community, see previous posts([here](https://superuser.com/questions/427389/making-website-accessible-to-the-internet)), I have reach the conditions where I am quite sure that I be able to access the web server through the internet.  This is what I have done:

1. Set the static ip at /etc/network/interfaces

   ```
   auth eth0
   ...inet static
   address ....
   netmask ...
   gateway ...
   ```
2. Set the /etc/hosts

   ```
   127.0.0.1  localhost
   [static_ip]  web-server
   ```
3. Set the /etc/resolv.conf to include my dns

   ```
   nameserver [dns-ip-primary]
   nameserver [dns-ip-secondary]
   search web-server
   ```

For your information, using the static IP the university gave me, I could do this in the server.

1. ping the default gateway
2. ping google via ip
3. ping google via address
4. access any website using lynx (text-based browser)

**Problem** But still, with these setup, I could not accessed my website via the internet but only via the local network.

I still does not know what I have miss, please guide me!

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Got ya! added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a firewall is blocking you. Did the network administration say your IP would be open to connections from the outside?

Comment: That's it...i am crazily frustrated with them.  Told them and will be ok, thanks a lot @DavidSchwartz